# List of ordered pairs from a dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I have a dataset with Keys Biz Unit, Rate, Average. Rate and Average are numerical values and I want to pull them from the dataset as a list of ordered pairs without the keys. I've tried various combinations of Flatten, Normal, and Part to achieve this but no success.

[image: This is a portion of the dataset, the name of the dataset is elastTI].

Comment: How about `ds[[All,2;;3]]`? If this is not useful, then please load the dataset as an image cannot be used by respondents.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have your dataset, so I will one from docs:

```
sales = SemanticImport["ExampleData/RetailSales.tsv"]
```

[image]

Numerical columns here are 1 and 3. The way to get the list of ordered pairs:

```
Normal@Values@sales[All, {1, 3}]
```